# in app purchase, Product with different types

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

i want to create an application which will be used by the user for 14 days lets say on trial basis, then the user have to pay once, if he continue using the app, how can i achieve that? and what product Type should i use? should i use 'Consumable' or 'non consumable' or 'Auto-renewable subscriptions' or 'Free subscriptions' or 'Non-renewing subscriptions'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i will be using Non renewing subscriptions, i have found the answer here in the docs.

```
Non-Renewing Subscription allow the sale of services with a limited duration. 

Non-Renewing Subscriptions must be used for in-app purchases that offer time-based 
access to static content and are only available to iOS apps.
If you use non-renewing subscription, your app is responsible for delivering the
subscription to all the user's devices.

Because a non-renewing subscription requires a user to renew each time, your app 
must contain code that recognizes when the subscription is due to expire. It must 
also prompt the user to purchase a new subscription.
```